# Angular Package Install

Tags: angular, npm

I want to install angular cli via npm cli when I run the command I am stuck and nothing happens after that

**npm install -g @angular/cli**

But it stuck in chokidar@1.7.0 checking installable status after some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a same problem but i recovered it using following command:

**npm install -g @angular/cli --verbos**

if its not work then you need to try yarn. you can download and install form https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/ this website

After install, run the following command

**yarn add @angular/cli**